# How to add API keys to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, api, heroku, api-key

I'm trying to add API keys to Heroku since my AngularJS/NodeJS application requires using them, but am having trouble. I tried using this plugin
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config but wasn't able to push the keys (it just hangs in there after I type in heroku:config push. Same thing happens with other commands). The plugin is no longer maintained so I was wondering if there's another way to approach this.

Currently I store my keys in .env file which I added to .gitignore, which I commit and push along with the other files. What steps would you suggest taking to add API keys to Heroku?

Comment: Are you able to add env keys via the Heroku dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Skelly notes, you can add API keys and the like as config vars via the Heroku Dashboard on the settings tab. You can also add/update etc [via the CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application)--e.g. `heroku config:set MY_API_KEY=12345`. Of course you have to have the [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) installed to use the CLI.

If you want to know more about why Heroku is like this, you should read [12factor.net](http://12factor.net/config) to understand the philosophy.